# Continue execution after downloading file from Amazon S3 using PHP

Tags: php, amazon-s3

I'm downloading a pdf file from S3 using the code below:

```
    try {

        $object = $s3->getObject(array(
        'Bucket' => $bucket,
        'Key'    => $keyname   
        ));
        header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
        header("Content-Encoding: none");
        header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.$keyname);
        header('Expires: 0');
        header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
        header('Pragma: public');
        header("Content-Type: {$object['ContentType']}");
        echo $object['Body'];
        //Code to be executed after downloading the file
        echo "test";
        $orig = "C:\\orig\\".$keyname;
        $dest = "C:\\dest\\".$keyname;
        rename($orig, $dest);
        
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        echo "Exception " . $e->getMessage();
    }
```

The problem here, is that I want to move this file from the default downloads folder to another one, but it seems like the script does not work after setting headers, I tried many solutions proposed previously in similar issues, but all failed, when I execute this script the file is downloaded successfully, but I don't see 'test' on browser and the file is not moved.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Do you see any output for `echo $object['Body'];` ?

Comment: In the downloaded file, yes, but the echo 'test' does not appear in the browser, actually, nothing appears in  the browser, but the file is downloaded successfully and i can view it from downloads folder. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you  tried to use the file_put_contents php function ? you can put the content  you recieve direclty into a file